# VS2017 will not connect to TFS2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs, visual-studio-2017

When attempting to set up a connection to TFS:

[image]

It finds the correct server; however, the **connect button is grayed out:**

[image]

**What am I doing wrong? Is VS2017 not compatible with TFS2012?**

I am able to connect to it with VS2013 without any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select server-level, indeed the connect button is grayed out. You need to select **collection-level** and then should be able to connect.

[image]

Your screenshot looks like lacking of the collection info. This error is similar to [Cannot connect to VSTS and TFS from VS 2017 RC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/3395/cannot-connect-to-vsts-and-tfs-from-vs-2017-rc.html)

> Thank you for your feedback! This issue has been fixed and it's
>   available in **VS2017 RC3** (26127). Thank you for helping us build a
>   better Visual Studio!
>
> *Added a solution by Visual Studio Team · 02/01 19:56*

You should make sure your vs version is later with VS2017RC3. And make sure you have enough permission to enter your collection.

Answer (score -1):

Visual Studio 2017 works with TFS 2013 or newer.  You have 2 options upgrade your TFS or use VS 2015.

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects

https://www.visualstudio.com/team-services/tfs-pricing/

Comment: TFS 2012 is supported by VS 2017 https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements under the Client Compatibility section